# Role of "einiges" in a comparative sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

The overall meaning of the following comic book sentence is relatively clear:

> Ich muss zugeben, Sie sind um **einiges** listiger, als ich dachte.
>
> *I must admit, you are a lot(?) more cunning than I thought.*

For comparatives with *um + noun*, my grammar book classifies them as describing a definite degree of difference, for example:

> Er ist (um) einen Monat jünger als ich.

Assuming that the adjective *einig*, means either "united" or "agreed", I am not sure what kind of noun *einiges* is pointing to, with or without ellipsis.

Sources:

1. *Lustiges Taschenbuch - Der Fluch der Hexe*,(LTB 538), pg.67
2. *Hammer's German Grammar and Usage - 3rd Edition*, Martin Durrell, Arnold 1996, pg. 157

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumption that "einiges" is related to "einig" is wrong.

"Einiges" is not an adjective, but describes an indefinite and "high" number of something (compare [duden.de](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/einige) 3rd meaning).

> Er ist (um) *einen Monat* jünger als ich. 
> Er ist um *einiges* jünger als ich. (He is a lot younger than I am.)

Your presumed translation from the beginning is therefore correct.

Comment: Is there any reason from the context why _einig-_ takes the _-es_ ending?  Thanks a lot for your answers, they helped a lot!

Comment: @SatishVasan As you can see [here](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/einige)  it's the ending of Neutrum Nominativ, Genitiv, Akkusativ.