# Rationale for einig- taking the Neutrum gender in a sentence

Tags: gender, indefinite-pronoun

In a [previous post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/65283/role-of-einiges-in-a-comparative-sentence) regarding *einiges* in the sentence:

> Ich muss zugeben, Sie sind um **einiges** listiger, als ich dachte.
>
> I must admit, you are a lot(?) more cunning than I thought.

choXer explained that *einiges* has the root *einig-*, with the meaning of "a lot" and is in the Neutrum gender.

I have not been able to work out why *einiges* has to be Neutrum, since cunning as a noun (die List) is feminine and it is not clear what else *einiges* is referring to.   Could someone please explain the logic of *einig-* taking the Neutrum gender?

Source:

Lustiges Taschenbuch - Der Fluch der Hexe,(LTB 538), pg.67

Comment: I can't see a noun in 'listig sein', but an Adjektiv, and 'einiges' refers to en amount, as in https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/einige, standing alone without an object. Like in Q: "Wieviel ?" A: "Einiges !".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Einiges" is not an adjective, it is a [indefinite pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronoun). These kinds of words do not "take" a gender from a related word, they have their own gender, which in this case is neuter.

Comment: This explanation is a bit misleading. Pronouns and related nouns need of course be congruent in gender, number, and sometimes even case - in general. In the example, however, we have an *indefinite pronoun*, there is no related noun, so no congruency.

Comment: @tofro: thanks. fixed it.